# How to draw on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

- I have a blue circle which is revolving around the red circle and both are moving to right combined.
- I need to draw on the canvas on the path of the red circle moves, but I don't want the blue circle to draw.
- at present the circle is moving along right but I want the circle to move in the direction of blue circle at the point of time of mouse press.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let positionX = 100;
let positionY = 100;
let X = 50;
let Y = 50;
let angle = 0;







function circle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function direction(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(positionX + X, positionY + Y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circle();
    direction();
    positionX = 35 * Math.sin(angle);
    positionY = 35 * Math.cos(angle);
    X+=1;

    angle += 0.1;

    canvas.addEventListener('onclick', function(){
   
    
    
        
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
}




animate();
```

```css
#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas basics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on `mousedown` create a path, on `mousedrag` add segments to that path using the coordinates of the mouse event. On `mouseup` finalize it in some way.

Comment: `canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    X += positionX;
    Y += positionY;
})` I have added its working but its not moving continuously in the direction and the rotating circle is not stopping while i mouse press